# Is it possible to only use a part of a string in a Switch-Statement?

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement

`savetext` is a string with a random length + "! Command1"

```
switch (savetext)
{
    case savetext.EndsWith("! Command1"):
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test1");
        break;

    case savetext.EndsWith("! Command2"):
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test2");
        break;

    default:
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(savetext)
        break;
}
```

The output should be "Test1" but my method here is isnt working like I want. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use an if/else in C# (it's possible to use pattern matching in a switch statement to do this, but it's uglier than the equivalent if/else)

Comment: You can only specify constant values for a case in a switch statement. You should use if/else if/else here

Comment: @OguzOzgul that's [not entirely true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements). You *can* write this as `case var _ when savetext.EndsWith("! Command1")`, but you might as well write `if (savetext.EndsWith("! Command1"))`

Comment: Or, get the last 10 characters of your string and use `case "! Command1": `

Comment: @canton7 thanks, I just can't see how pattern matching applies here.

Comment: @OguzOzgul `var _` is a pattern, and `when` is grouped under "pattern matching" in the documentation. See my previous comment for an example of how to combine these to do what the OP wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the suffix you're looking for always has the same length, you could extract it using `Substring`, and then `switch` on that:

```cs
String switcher = savetext.Substring(savetext.Length - 10);
switch (switcher)
{
    case "! Command1":
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test1");
        break;

    case "! Command2":
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test2");
        break;

    default:
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(savetext)
        break;
}
```

Comment: If you do this, be careful to check that `savetext.Length` is 10 or more, otherwise you might get an exception if it's too short

Comment: Oh Cool, that helps me a lot! But what is when i also have a random suffix lenth?

Answer (score 0):

A [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#positional-patterns) in C# 8:

```
var saveText = "111 ! Command1";
var logText = saveText switch
{
    var x when x.EndsWith("! Command1") => "Test 1",
    var x when x.EndsWith("! Command2") => "Test 2",
    var x => x
};

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logText);
```